# Degree of dependency in the law of conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The theorem of conditional probability has it that if P(A|B)=P(A) then the two events are independent. However, I wonder is there any intuition behind the numerical differences if two of them differ? E.g. if P(A|B) and P(A) are just differ by 0.01 (or even 0.001) that we can claim the strength of dependency is weak, while if the numerical difference hits like >= 0.1 or something we can claim that, compared to 0.01, the two probabilities indeed has relatively large dependency.

Please advise if my interpretation/intuition is right or wrong - or even, are there anyone describing and comparing in this way? TIA.

Comment: +1 to your posting: In my opinion, your analogy and analysis is spot-on.  Consider a lottery where the numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,1000000\}$ are selected, one at a time, without replacement.  Assume that the winning number is (for example) $(7)$.  Consider the probability of the 2nd person who selects a number at random, wins the lottery, given that the first person did not win the lottery.  The 2nd person's probability of winning is (almost) unaffected by the fact that the 1st person did not win.

Comment: Independence is $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(\color{red}{A})$.  Or that when these are no zero probabilities:$$\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(A)}=1$$

Comment: Also, Bayes' Rule states $\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(A)}= \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$. So...